# Python FastAPI multiple method with same route does not work

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I am facing trouble with FastAPI when I do multiple method with the same route on a router.

When I define with the decorator `@router.get("/route/")` and `@router.post("/route/")` for example different functions, when I do my `requests.post()`, that will ask me params like if I was doing a GET request on the endpoint and consider only the GET endpoint.

Is it possible to have a route that handle both GET and POST methods?

Here is the example of FastAPI main.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app.routers import test

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(test.router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="...", port=...)
```

Here would be the router:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, UploadFile, File, HTTPException, Response, status

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/test",
    tags=["test"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

@router.get("/route/{arg_test}/")
def get_function(arg_test:str, agr_2_test:int):
    # do something
    pass

@router.post("/route/{arg_test}/")
def post_function(arg_test:str, json_data:dict):
    # do something
    pass
```

With this script, when I do the following script, it will request the GET endpoint instead of the post:

```
import requests

data = {"test_attribute":"test"}

requests.post(f"{url_fastapi}/route/{arg_test}/", json=data)
```

I guess that I can do something with the `Request` class in order to concatenate both request method into the same `@router.route()` decorator and splitting the process inside of the function according to the method but I would like to keep the logical of use the decorators `@router.get("/route/")` and `@router.post("/route/").`

Answer (score 2):

The code behaves as expected, so I'm guessing there's something outside of the code you've included that is the issue. Self-contained example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, UploadFile, File, HTTPException, Response, status
import uvicorn

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/test",
    tags=["test"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

@router.get("/route/{arg_test}/")
def get_function(arg_test:str, agr_2_test:int):
    return {"op": "GET"}

@router.post("/route/{arg_test}/")
def post_function(arg_test:str, json_data:dict):
    return {"op": "POST"}

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, port=5500)
```

And when making requests:

```py
>>> requests.get("http://localhost:5500/test/route/foo/?agr_2_test=2").json()
{'op': 'GET'}
>>> requests.post("http://localhost:5500/test/route/foo/", json={"foo": "bar"}).json()
{'op': 'POST'}
```